# Column generation is exact or heuristic algorithm?

Tags: optimization

I know that column generation gives an optimal solution and it can be used with other heuristics. But does that make it an exact algorithm? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional CG operates on the relaxed problem. Although it finds the optimal LP solution, this may not translate directly into an optimal MIP solution. For some problems (e.g. 1d cutting stock) there is evidence this gap is small, and we just apply the set of columns found for the relaxed problem to a final MIP knowing this is a good solution but necessarily optimal. So it is a heuristic.

With some effort you can use column generation inside a branch-and-bound algorithm (this is called branch-and-price). This gives proven optimal solutions.

Answer (score 0):

An **exact algorithm** means that the algorithm can solve the optimization problem globally i.e it has given the global optima.

**Column generation** technique is conventionally applied to relaxed LP problem and tries to optimize the relaxed LP problem by constantly improving the current solution with the help of dual multipliers. It gives an exact LP solution for the relaxed LP problem. But sometimes in real-world problems, the exact solution of the relaxed Lp problem is not feasible to use, it needs to be translated to an integer solution in order to use it. Now if the problem scale is small, then there are many exact MIP algorithms (such as Branch and Bound) which can solve it exactly and give an integer solution. But if the problem is large-scale, even the exact MIP algorithms can take longer runtimes, hence, we use some special/intelligent heuristics to lower the difficulty of the MIP problem.

*Summary*: Column generation is an exact technique for solving the relaxed LP problem, not the original IP problem.

Answer (score -1):

First, strictly speaking, all algorithms are heuristic, including Simplex Method.
Second, I think Column generation is a heuristic algorithm, because it solves the LP relaxation of the master problem. It does not guarantee IP optimal. Actually CG does not always converge very well.